# how to make express port to listen to nodemailer port

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, zoho, cloud9

I have been having issues trying to use my zoho mail account with nodemailer in my cloud 9 workspace. When i send the request all it returns back after some time is connection timeout. i contacted my dns name provider they told me to ensure that port 465 is open in my server.. but am really stuck don't know how to change it or to check it any help

**how i listen to port in my express app**

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
    console.log(process.env.PORT)
})
```

how do i configure it to listen to other ports like 465 and get my nodemailer working..

Answer (score 0):

Since you're listening on the port specified in your process environment variables, run your app passing it in via `PORT`:

On Unix:

`PORT=465 node <appFile>.js`

If you're on windows you can use [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to pass in the Environment variables, you'll just need to install it globally with `npm i -g cross-env`.

`cross-env PORT=465 node <appFile>js`

Comment: Thanks for replying if i export 465 to my environment variable and set it to be what my app is listening to won't it stop the app from running..